# Проверка массива на число

Tags: javascript

Как проверить вложенный массив, есть ли в нем число или строка?

```
const a = [
  [1,2,3],
  ['a','b','c'],
  [ 4,5,6],
  ['d','e','f'],
  [ 7,8,9],
];
```

Comment: так же как и обычный массив